# Compare two Set <String> and return list<String> that does'nt exist in Set2

Tags: apex, trigger, map, nested, for

I am getting the desired result, but I want to avoid the nested FOR in my code. However my attempt failed. This is the best I could do. Can someone please guide me how I can avoid the nested FOR?

```
 // I have two multiselect picklist fields on a Account object: Located_States__c, Supported_States__c
// for every record, i want to compare the values in these two fields and 
// get a list of values from Located_States__c that do not exist in Supported_States__c
//e.g Located_States__c = {'AR'; 'MD'; 'CO'; 'IN'}, Supported_States__c = {'AR'; 'MD'} ,
//ValuesFromLocatedThatDontExistInSupported: 'CO', 'IN'



List <Account> accList = [Select ID, Name, Located_States__c, Supported_States__c 
                        FROM Account Where (Located_States__c != NULL || Supported_States__c != NULL)];

set<string> supportedstates =new set<string>();     


String  ValuesFromLocatedThatDontExistInSupported = '';

Boolean Start = true;

for(Account acc: accList){

    for(string str : acc.Supported_States__c.split(';')){
        supportedstates.add(str);
    }

    for(string str1 : acc.Located_States__c.split(';')){     
        if(!supportedstates.contains(str1)){                    
             if(Start) {
                ValuesFromLocatedThatDontExistInSupported = str1;                                   
                Start = false;
             } else {               
                ValuesFromLocatedThatDontExistInSupported = ValuesFromLocatedThatDontExistInSupported + ';' + str1;         
               }
               acc.Remaining_State__c = ValuesFromLocatedThatDontExistInSupported;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Yep, pretty clear case for the `removeAll()` method, I think.

Comment: This will have all supported states from previous Accounts, is that intended or is the set supposed to be reset on each iteration?